# iPhone sliding menu with multiple navigation controllers iOS xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6

I have been trying to create a sliding menu for iPhone app using storyboards. I have played around with a load of code examples I have found online on StackOverflow and code4apps example,
however all of these were based on xibs, and I didn't have much luck. I have gone through [Ray Wenderlich's Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) and [the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com) as well as StackOverflow and Youtube and so far I have had no luck.

I have managed to set up a scroll view with 8 round rect buttons but when I try to set up a segue from of these buttons to a navigation control, the only option is action segue - push which then crashes with the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
```

I have tried modal and custom but modal messes up the top bar nav and I don't know custom code to stop this error.

Any help on where I am going wrong here would be amazing, [here is an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cloj-deVmfg) of one for The Beatles love app, 4 buttons on each slide. - and an indication with page control - this is exactly what im trying to achieve..

Answer (score 1):

The built in story board segues are only for the built in classes like UINavigationController. You will need a custom UIStoryBoardSegue

Comment: ok thanks, i tried a custom one like explain in the post here http://www.cmumobileapps.com/2011/11/04/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-segues/ but i stil get the same error..

Comment: Well you cannot push a navigation controller onto a navigation controller. Just push a normal view controller.

Comment: ok rite, then a custom segue wont work to push navigation controller to navigation controller. ill look for another way without embedding in navigation controller. not really sure where to go from here..

Comment: Well you probably don't want two navigation bars so I don't see why you would need to push another UINavigationController. Just push the view controller you want.